# What examples are there of animated toolbar icons?

Tags: animation, toolbar

Are there applications (including web applications) that have animated toobar icons? I would imagine they would only animate on hover/mouse over, but I'd be interested to show someone this so we can discuss it. Personally I think it's a bad idea, but that's my subjective opinion. All I want is an example I can use without having to create one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to dive into the subject there is a paper called "[Bringing Icons to Life](http://books.google.se/books?id=gjm6FpMUTXgC&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=bringing+icons+to+life&source=bl&ots=RhaArIvKqV&sig=ghzny6-P1g61q25d-Nt_eTwufbk&hl=sv&ei=gEHgTLr6OsqXOp_g1ekO&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=bringing%20icons%20to%20life&f=false)" by Ronald Baecker, Ian Small and Richard Mander (found it on Google Books). Bare in mind it is from 1991.